# Single supply analog gate current mode switching

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog-switch

I need to switch a bunch of analog signals, in the \$\pm10\$ volt range, with the control coming from a microcontroller. Since the signals are all ending up in the virtual ground node of an opamp, I'm using current mode switching, as that allows using an analog gate with a much smaller signal range than otherwise necessary. Putting an example of that into schematic form, where we're switching the gain of an opamp stage:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdI1AP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In this circuit, SW1 determines whether the input resistor is \$100k\Omega\$ or \$1.5k\Omega \parallel 100k\Omega \$. Note that since the switch is connected  either to the virtual or the actual ground, voltage over the switch is always \$\frac{\mathrm{Vin}R_{on}}{R_2}\$, which is quite small.

So my question is: what happens if SW1 is an analog switch with a single supply voltage? For example, [the TS3A5018](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ts3a5018.pdf). Looking at fig 1 of the datasheet, at least the on-resistance even at zero voltage is just a few ohms, and unless it rises essentially discontinously, the switch terminals shouldn't be more than \$100\$mV below ground. On the other hand, this is out of spec, and also the datasheet doesn't really give any data hinting at what \$R_{off}\$ is when the input is slightly negative.

The reason I'd want to do this is that single supply analog switches are more plentiful, available in a wider variety of packages, often cheaper for similar performance, and I've got a 3.3V analog rail anyway. With a normal \$\pm6\$V or so 4053 or similar, I'd have to generate the analog switch power rails separately from the main \$\pm 12\$V supplies.

The question: am I right in thinking that this is not going to work? If so, how does this fail to work? Is there any way around having to throw in two more regulators or using an expensive \$\pm12\$V analog switch?

Comment: I would probably use a pair of back to back logic level N channel MOSFETs to implement the switch.

Comment: A relay would probably be cheaper than adding a negative rail just to supply a dual supply analog switch.

Comment: @Null I'm very short on PCB space...

Comment: And there's several switch sections (four, or maybe three, I might be able to drop one section by compromising elsewhere if I really need to)

Comment: Solid state relays come in pretty small packages, surely taking up less space than an analog switch plus regulator(s).

Comment: @Null Thanks for the tip! I took a quick look, the cheapest SSR I could find was 50 cents a pop, whereas the cheapest triple analog SPDT switches are about 25 cents, i.e. about 8 cents per switch. I do have \$\pm12\$V rails, so using a \$3.3\$V dual rail switch I only really need one regulator to make the negative rail (almost any voltage will do). I can find at first glance a 0.64$ regulator in a SOT23-3, so overall I get about 30 cents per channel. For three switches, using a 4053 in TSSOP-16, I get \$41,8mm^2\$ total for the switch and reg, and \$73,2mm^2\$ for three relays.

Comment: So that was close! Do you have experience on using SSR's for signal switching? The datasheets don't seem to give for example Ron vs. input voltage curves, which makes me think they're more aimed at power switching etc?

Comment: @PeterSmith thanks for the suggestion! That doesn't quite work as an SPST, since the input signal is \$\pm10\mathrm{V}\$, so the negative peaks open the channel. However, connecting two pairs as an SPDT, like in my schematic, this works (this is probably what you meant anyway?). However, here's the kicker: since the voltages are way below a diode drop in this case, I only need one pair, one for switching the current to the opamp on/off and the other for switching it to ground, as the parasitic diode never becomes conductive! Would you like to write an answer based on this?

Comment: Yes, I've used an SSR in a similar application to control an op amp amplifier's gain. I would just use a SPST to disconnect \$R_2\$, so the gain would be either \$-R_3/R_1\$ or \$-R_3/(R_1 \parallel R_2)\$.